# C++ overloading array operator

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading, heap

I'm creating a Heap, like this:

```
struct Heap {
    int H[100];
    int operator [] (int i) { return H[i]; }
    //...    
};
```

When I try to print elements from it I do like this:

```
Heap h;
// add some elements...
printf("%d\n", h[3]); // instead of h.H[3]
```

If, instead of accessing, I want to set them, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) h[i] = i;
```

how can I do?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is idiomatic to provide couple of overloads of the `operator[]` function - one for `const` objects and one for non-`const` objects. The return type of the `const` member function can be a `const&` or just a value depending on the object being returned while the return type of the non-`const` member function is usually a reference.

```
struct Heap{
    int H[100];
    int operator [] (int i) const {return H[i];}
    int& operator [] (int i) {return H[i];}
};
```

This allows you to modify a non-`const` object using the array operator.

```
Heap h1;
h1[0] = 10;
```

while still allowing you to access `const` objects.

```
Heap const h2 = h1;
int val = h2[0];
```

Comment: Array subscript operator:
User-defined classes that provide array-like access that allows both reading and writing typically define two overloads for operator[]: const and non-const variants: 


`struct T { value_t& operator[](std::size_t idx) return mVector[idx]; 
    const value_t& operator[](std::size_t idx) const return mVector[idx]; 
};` [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

Answer (score 7):

You can return references to what should be set. Add `&` to the return type.

```
int& operator [] (int i){return H[i];}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should return by reference. With your current version you are taking a copy and editing this copy which will not affect the original array. You have to change your operator overloading to this:

```
int& operator [] (int i){return H[i];}
```