# Operator [ ] overloading with const and non const versions

Tags: c++

I started learning C++ not long ago and I've got an issue.
I know that a lot of similar questions has been asked about this topic.
However, I didn't deeply understand something which is why I am here.

So, my question is: 
why do I need to provide 2 versions of the [] operator? 
isn't the const version sufficient?

For example, I have been working on an Array class: (The last 2 operators are the relevant ones)

```
   class Array
    {
    private:
        int* _arrPtr;
        int _len;
    public:
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Array& other);
        friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Array& other);
        Array(int len = 10, int val = 0);
        Array(const Array& other);
        ~Array();
        void setArray(int len);
        int* getArray() const;
        void setLen(int len) { this->_len = len; }
        int getLen() const { return this->_len; }
        Array operator+(const Array& other) const;
        Array& operator=(const Array& other);
        Array operator+(int val); 
        int& operator[](int index) const;
        int& operator[](int index);
    };
```

**can I replace the two operators**

```
int& operator[](int index) const;
int& operator[](int index);
```

**only with the const one?**

```
int& operator[](int index) const;
```

Wouldn't it be the same??? wouldn't it be the same for any operator overloading if the there is only one const version of the operator?(under the assumption that all of the const methods do have the word 'const' at the end of their declaration)

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043078/c-overloading-array-operator answer your question?

Comment: _"wouldn't it be the same for any operator overloading if the there is only one const version of the operator?"_ No, that wouldn't be the same. Do you understand what `const` after a function declaration actually means?

Comment: @RSahu it helps, but my question is if the replacement of the 2 operators only with the CONST one will lead to the same result

Comment: @CodeLearner, you need the non-const version in order to be able change the container.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ hmm yes I think, a const method cannot change the dms of the class. the type of this will be const * <class>.

Comment: @RSahu but i can change the container even without the non-const version.
the assignment operator is the one who changes the container, not the [] operator

Comment: @CodeLearner, you can but that's not idiomatic. Changing the contents of a `const` object is never a good idea. There are extenuating circumstances where you must do that but that's supported through the `mutable` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not you need two overloads depends on what interface you want to provide.

If you want to be able to modify elements even in `const` instances of `Array`, then yes, the single `int& operator[](int index) const;` is enough. This is what [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_at) does.

But if you want elements of `const` `Array`s to be read-only, and at the same time elements of non-`const` `Array`s to be mutable, you need two overloads. [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) does that.

Usually the second option is preferred.

Comment: now I understand what I miss. Why will the const array be modified, it is const. 
 Am i not supposed to get an error?

Comment: @CodeLearner When a function is marked `const`, all member of the class work as if they were `const` inside of it. E.g. inside of `int& operator[](int index) const;` `_len = ...;` or `_arrPtr = ...;` indeed would give you a compile-time error. But even when a pointer (`_arrPtr`) becomes `const`, what it points to doesn't. `*_arrPtr` and `_arrPtr[i]` are allowed even in `const` functions. This is just how the language is designed, presumably this gives you more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write `int& operator[](int index) const;`. Instead, you need to write:

```
const int& operator[](int index) const;
int& operator[](int index);
```

Why is this so? Because if something is `const`, you can have only const references to it or it's elements, as non-const referenes whould let you change it, which you have no right to.

If you want const references when the thing is const and non-const references in case the thing is not const, you need the overloading.  If you only want const references in any case, you may get without the overloading.

Comment: But it compiles without the const.

Comment: @Code it may be syntactically allowed, but does allowing modification of the state of `const` objects make sense? https://ideone.com/xySwnn